# C# LINQ Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem with `Include()` in Entity Framework.

I have some entities

```
public partial class Travel_RequestEmployee
{
 public virtual Traveler Traveler { get; set; }
}

public abstract partial class Traveler{
}

public partial class Traveler_Employee : Traveler
{
 public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

I want to Include Employee Properties from `Travel_RequestEmployee`. Is there a  way to get `Include()` working like this?

```
_context.Travel_RequestEmployee.Include(x => 
x.Traveler.OfType<Traveler_Employee>().Include(e => e.Employee));
```

Please help me?

Comment: I only know how this works with EF.... database modeling. Could you show more code as to how you are defining your logic. i.e EF(entity framework) will not know your intention. If this is with EF then i suggest you should your logical data relationships.. as that defines what EF knows about your structure..saying that it will not know what you are trying to do. If this is not EF then i suggest more code as to the implementation of include. I could be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong type.

```
public partial class Travel_RequestEmployee
{
 public virtual Traveler_Employee Traveler { get; set; }
}
```

notice the switch to Traveler_Employee. Traveler is a base class.

Comment: No. It's my relationship in DB. In Db => I designed like this: Travel_RequestEmployee 1 : 1 Traveler table. Traveler 1 : 1 Traveler_Employee, Traveler table 1: 1 to another table

Comment: you should still change to the correct type. The base type doesn't know which class it is inherited by. It is the other way around, your class knows it is inherited by Traveler.

Comment: In this case. If I have new table Traveler_Candidate : Traveler. At this time, the Travel_RequestEmployee will have new property Traveler_Candidate. Therefore, it will break my design before